# Automating File Move from Marketing Cloud SFTP Import to Export Folder

Tags: marketing-cloud, reporting, automation, ftp, sftp

Attempting to automate moving a report from Marketing Cloud's Import Folder to the Export folder, or from the Reports folder to the Export folder,  and encrypt it. However, I don't show that the file transfer offers this capability, only to export from Marketing Cloud's Safehouse location. Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, you can't create a report definition and send it to the Marketing Cloud Safehouse. Is there a way to automate a file transfer from one Marketing Cloud SFTP folder to another?

Comment: What's the specific use case?

Comment: Sorry, I misclicked and can't remove the downvote myself :(

Comment: No worries. Use case is this: We need a report input to our export folder on the Marketing Cloud SFTP. My workflow would be to go Report Definition --> Reports or Import Folder --> Export Folder via Data Extract (we've provisioned that capability). However, the import has to be encrypted, and from what I can tell there's no way to encrypt a report definition or send it to the Marketing Cloud Safehouse. If I could send to the safehouse, I could then encrypt via File Transfer, but it doesn't look like that's a possibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is how I resolved my quandary:

Automation = Report Definition> Import File into a Data Extension > Data Extract (Data Extension) > File Transfer and encrypt, dropping to export folder.

Answer (score 4):

Salesforce Support are able to provision few custom Data Extracts having different functionalities, e.g. for deleting files. I seem to remember there is also an option of one specific type being able to move files across folders on Enhanced FTP.

Comment: Yes, you remember correctly. ;) we have extract types to move and delete enabled in a customer account.

Comment: We have that provisioned, but unfortunately we have to encrypt the file. So the only way would be to have it sent to the Safehouse, encrypt it, and then drop it. But I don't believe Marketing cloud allows you to send Reports to the Safehouse nor encrypt them.

Answer (score 1):

You can request Salesforce Support to provision the Data Extract Activity "Enhanced FTP File Move and Copy" to your account which gives you the option to move or copy from one folder to the other. I would love to add link to documentation, but when I asked why this is not documented I was told it was because this is not an officially supported feature *sigh*

Comment: Just knowing the "Enhanced FTP File Move and Copy" option exists is half the battle. I sigh with you.